# Liquibase - Update changelog XML file from database changes

Tags: java, database, maven, version-control, liquibase

I decided to use liquibase on my Java project with Postgresql, so I created initial changeset using `generateChangeLog` maven goal. Now it is working without any problems.

What I am looking for is after I made a change on the database (let's say from a  RDBMS client), is there any command to analyze the changelog and the database status to generate changeset from my changes and append it to the changeset xml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `diffChangelog` command: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/diff.html

> In change log mode, an XML change log of what is necessary to
>   upgrade the base database to the target database is sent to standard
>   out. This change log can be included as is, or copied into an existing
>   change log. If the diff command is passed an existing change log file,
>   the new change sets will be appended to the end of the file.

Comment: This command compares two seperate **databases** and outputs the changelog. What I need is to compare the database and the changelog xml file (with changesets) and find out the difference between them.

Comment: In that case, you could apply the changelog to a second database and then compare the two databases.